# Simplify Repeated tag values jQuery / Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code snippet and I'm wondering if there is any way to make it more simple.

My Code:

```
     var arr = $(".countrycode").toArray();
     for ( var i = 0, l = arr.length; i < l; i++ ) {
        var tagValue = $("#"+arr[i].id).attr("data-continent");
        if(tagValue=="na"||tagValue=="sa"){
            $(".select-us").attr("disabled",false);
        }
         if(tagValue=="oc"){
            $(".select-oc").attr("disabled",false);
        }
         if(tagValue=="eu"){
            $(".select-eu").attr("disabled",false);
        }
         if(tagValue=="as"){
            $(".select-as").attr("disabled",false);
        }
    }
```

Thank you for looking into this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Also the third way is combining `$.fn.each` and `if statement` like this:

```
$('.countrycode').each(function(){
    var tagValue = $(this).attr("data-continent");
    var lttrs = tagValue == "na" || tagValue == "sa" ? "us" : tagValue;
   $(`.select-${lttrs}`).attr("disabled",false);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

No need to convert a jQuery collection to array when you can use the built in [`$.fn.each`](https://api.jquery.com/each/) iterator

```
$(".countrycode").each(function(){
   // `this` is current element instance
   var tagValue = $(this).attr("data-continent"); 
   if(tagValue ....  )
   ....

})
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try with this.

```
var arr = $(".countrycode").toArray();
for ( var i = 0, l = arr.length; i < l; i++ ) {
   var tagValue = $("#"+arr[i].id).attr("data-continent");
   var element = tagValue == "na" || tagValue == "sa" ? "us" : tagValue;
   $(`.select-${element}`).attr("disabled",false);
}
```